# TypeError in python when populating data in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, ipython

I am getting **TypeError** in **Python3** when I try to populate the data after **splitting** the dataset,

**code** :

```
test_size = 0.2
train_set = {2:[],4:[]}
test_set = {2:[],4:[]}
train_data = full_data[:-int(test_size*len(full_data))]
test_data = full_data[-int(test_size*len(full_data)):]    
len(train_data),len(test_data)
for i in train_data:
    train_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])

for i in test_data:
    test_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])
```

here **dataset** is `full_data` which is `list of list` of **float values**

**error**:

```
      1 for i in train_data:
----> 2     train_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])
      3 
      4 for i in test_data:
      5     test_set[i[-1]].append(i[:-1])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Some of the values in `full_data` might not be what you think they are. Try putting in a `print(i)` to check what the value is before the glitch happens.

Comment: Please always post the full stack trace of error when asking.